# Simulating "focus" and "blur" in jQuery .live() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Update:** As of jQuery 1.4, `$.live()` now supports *focusin* and *focusout* events.

---

[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) currently<sup>1</sup> doesn't support "blur" or "focus" as arguments for the [$.live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) method. What type of work-around could I implement to achieve the following:

```
$("textarea")
  .live("focus", function() { foo = "bar"; })
  .live("blur",  function() { foo = "fizz"; });
```

<sup>**1**. 07/29/2009, version 1.3.2</sup>

Comment: $('textarea').bind('focus') works... In your code sample don't you mean "live()"??

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Working solution:**

```
(function(){

    var special = jQuery.event.special,
        uid1 = 'D' + (+new Date()),
        uid2 = 'D' + (+new Date() + 1);

    jQuery.event.special.focus = {
        setup: function() {
            var _self = this,
                handler = function(e) {
                    e = jQuery.event.fix(e);
                    e.type = 'focus';
                    if (_self === document) {
                        jQuery.event.handle.call(_self, e);
                    }
                };

            jQuery(this).data(uid1, handler);

            if (_self === document) {
                /* Must be live() */
                if (_self.addEventListener) {
                    _self.addEventListener('focus', handler, true);
                } else {
                    _self.attachEvent('onfocusin', handler);
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        },
        teardown: function() {
            var handler = jQuery(this).data(uid1);
            if (this === document) {
                if (this.removeEventListener) {
                    this.removeEventListener('focus', handler, true);
                } else {
                    this.detachEvent('onfocusin', handler);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    jQuery.event.special.blur = {
        setup: function() {
            var _self = this,
                handler = function(e) {
                    e = jQuery.event.fix(e);
                    e.type = 'blur';
                    if (_self === document) {
                        jQuery.event.handle.call(_self, e);
                    }
                };

            jQuery(this).data(uid2, handler);

            if (_self === document) {
                /* Must be live() */
                if (_self.addEventListener) {
                    _self.addEventListener('blur', handler, true);
                } else {
                    _self.attachEvent('onfocusout', handler);
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        },
        teardown: function() {
            var handler = jQuery(this).data(uid2);
            if (this === document) {
                if (this.removeEventListener) {
                    this.removeEventListener('blur', handler, true);
                } else {
                    this.detachEvent('onfocusout', handler);
                }
            }
        }
    };

})();
```

Tested in IE/FF/Chrome. Should work exactly as you intended.

UPDATE: Teardowns now work.

Comment: Now go to the jQuery bug tracker and provide the patch. Good job.

Comment: Will `die()` route to `teardown` here?

Comment: Yep, I think so... jQuery takes care of most of it in the background (including the "handling"). Just updated the teardowns so the appropriate events are detached.

Comment: Many Thanks.  Solved a problem I was having perfectly.

Comment: how do you use this function?

Comment: NOTE: this is no longer necessary. jQuery 1.4 supports this natively, via the `focusin` and `focusout` events.

Comment: Just a suggestion: in the above code sample, `+new Date()` can be shortened to `+new Date`. The brackets aren’t required (unless you need to pass arguments, of course).

Answer (score 5):

This functionality is now included in jQuery core (as of 1.4.1).

Answer (score 2):

`live()` is jQuery's shortcut to [event delegation](http://briancrescimanno.com/2008/05/19/an-introduction-to-javascript-event-delegation/). To answer your question, see [Delegating the focus and blur events](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html).

It's pretty ingenious: for standards compliant browsers he uses [event capturing](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-capture) to trap those events. For IE he uses IE's proprietary `focusin` (for `focus`) and `focusout` (for `blur`) events, which do bubble, allowing traditional event delegation.

I'll leave the porting of it to jQuery as an exercise.

Comment: Did the port :) (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

they have been added on jquery 1.4.1   ... now .live() function supports fucus and blur events =)  Greetings

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is when checking the event.type it returns "focusin" & "focusout"

```
$('input').live("focus blur", function(event){
    if (event.type == "focusin") {
        console.log(event.type);
    }else{
        console.log(event.type);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one more addition: this solution does not support more than one parameter.

i tried:

```
$(el).live("focus blur",  function(e) {
  if (e.type == "focus") {
```

etc.

and it only fired the blur event.

nevertheless this solution has been helpful.