# jQuery .live() check (with focus/blur)

Tags: jquery, focus, live, blur

I know that focus and blur events don't work with .live() before jQuery 1.4.1. A mod was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199293/simulating-focus-and-blur-in-jquery-live-method) that allows focus/blur events to be used with .live() for older jQuery versions.

I'm writing a script that (hopefully) people will use, and I can't be sure which version of jQuery they are using. Is there any way to check if jQuery focus/blur events work with .live() out of the box (i.e. a newer version of jQuery), and if not, implement the accepted solution in the above link?

Comment: You can basically try to find the version of jquery and implement accordingly.

Comment: "$().jquery" will give you the current jquery version.

Comment: yup it will be but you will atleast know which version onwards it supports this feature.

Comment: @chrislegend - I hope this will atleast help you in some way :) If you find it helpful please accept my answer thanks.

Comment: @chrislegend - Did you find any better solution?