# focus / blur don't fire

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a project that uses the **old jQuery 1.3.2**. I need to `blur` input value on `focus` and return it (if not changed) on `focusout` (can't use `placeholder` here).

This is what I'm doing:

```
console.log('start');
$('input[type=text]').live('focus', function() {
    console.log('focused');
    if (!$(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).data('defaultText', $(this).val());
    if ($(this).val()==$(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).val('');
});
$('input[type=text]').live('blur', function() {
    console.log('blurred');
    if ($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText')); 
});
```

I see `start` in the console, but then nothing on focusing the inputs. What should I change here?

Comment: You never mentioned if you're also using an old browser.

Comment: Nope, latest chrome.

Comment: In jQuery 1.3.x only the following JavaScript events (in addition to custom events) could be bound with .live(): click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.

Comment: Ah thats it, I found a working solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1199651/172637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function(){

    var special = jQuery.event.special,
        uid1 = 'D' + (+new Date()),
        uid2 = 'D' + (+new Date() + 1);

    jQuery.event.special.focus = {
        setup: function() {
            var _self = this,
                handler = function(e) {
                    e = jQuery.event.fix(e);
                    e.type = 'focus';
                    if (_self === document) {
                        jQuery.event.handle.call(_self, e);
                    }
                };

            jQuery(this).data(uid1, handler);

            if (_self === document) {
                /* Must be live() */
                if (_self.addEventListener) {
                    _self.addEventListener('focus', handler, true);
                } else {
                    _self.attachEvent('onfocusin', handler);
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        },
        teardown: function() {
            var handler = jQuery(this).data(uid1);
            if (this === document) {
                if (this.removeEventListener) {
                    this.removeEventListener('focus', handler, true);
                } else {
                    this.detachEvent('onfocusin', handler);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    jQuery.event.special.blur = {
        setup: function() {
            var _self = this,
                handler = function(e) {
                    e = jQuery.event.fix(e);
                    e.type = 'blur';
                    if (_self === document) {
                        jQuery.event.handle.call(_self, e);
                    }
                };

            jQuery(this).data(uid2, handler);

            if (_self === document) {
                /* Must be live() */
                if (_self.addEventListener) {
                    _self.addEventListener('blur', handler, true);
                } else {
                    _self.attachEvent('onfocusout', handler);
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        },
        teardown: function() {
            var handler = jQuery(this).data(uid2);
            if (this === document) {
                if (this.removeEventListener) {
                    this.removeEventListener('blur', handler, true);
                } else {
                    this.detachEvent('onfocusout', handler);
                }
            }
        }
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) in jquery 1.3.2

```
$('input[type="text"]').bind('focus',function() {
  console.log('focused'); 
 });
 $('input[type=text]').bind('blur', function() {
   console.log('blurd');
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ss6mgdur/)

Comment: it doesn't support focus and blur either

Comment: @3zzy it's  working fine in example and i am using same jquery file check in console

Comment: just confirmed again, this same code doesn't work on my end. either way, I'm using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199293/simulating-focus-and-blur-in-jquery-live-method/1199651#1199651